# Multisite new sites not found(404), main site still works

Tags: multisite, 404-error

I followed wordpress [guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_2%3a_Allow_Multisite) to install multisite. My main site (mydomain.com) works well, my multisite is based on subdirectory i.e., (mydomain.com/test/), however it doesn't load at all (404 error).
more details

```
 $ cat .htaccess

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /wordpress/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

---

```
 $ cat wp-config.php

/* Multisite */
 define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

 define('MULTISITE', true);
 define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
 define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomain.com');
 define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');
 define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
 define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

---

It will be great if you can help to fix it. thanks

Comment: You turned Pretty Permalinks on, presumably? Are you able to view your server's log files (access and/or error logs) to see what request is *actually* being made on the server?

Comment: Permalinks set to default, I just enabled log define('WP_DEBUG', true); on wp-config.php, but I can't see debug.log file under /wp-content/.

Comment: More details, I reinstalled. Previously I had subdirectory in the URL (I did set under setting/general), now everything is in my root folder. After the multisite installation, I'm facing new problem, i.e., the new site does open but without any styles (html inspector says it is looking for CSS under my domain.com/test/wp-includes.......). This is of course wrong!! I'm nginx web server. How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't believe Nginx uses `.htaccess` files, at least not out of the box. [Googling 'convert .htaccess for nginx'](https://www.google.ca/search?q=convert+.htaccess+for+nginx) may help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multisite 404 error for subdirectory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167294/multisite-404-error-for-subdirectory)

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same error with both Nginx and Apache installed. Nginx works as a reverse proxy and serves static files. Because of this reason you have to insert the following code inside server directive:

```
if ( !-e $request_filename ) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;  
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;                     
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;                   
}
```

If you use Nginx as reverse proxy for static files you have to put the code listed above  inside a location. i.e:

```
location ~ ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG|ICO|CSS|ZIP|TGZ|GZ|RAR|BZ2|DOC|XLS|EXE|PDF|PPT|TXT|TAR|WAV|BMP|RTF|JS) {
if ( !-e $request_filename ) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
}
```

If you run nginx + php-fpm (no Apache and further url rewriting with `mod_rewrite` involved) you have to put the code inside server directive.