# 404 error in dashboard of subdomain of multisite

Tags: multisite, htaccess

I am getting a 404 error whenever I click to ender the dashboard of my subdomain and on the front end, I am getting an "Index Of /" for the same subdomain.  I've followed the instructions in the link below and some tips from the next link, but seems like something is still missing.

https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/multisite
[multisite 404 error for subdirectory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167294/multisite-404-error-for-subdirectory)

My .htaccess file is a txt file and looks like this:

```
# Begin Wordpress 
# The directiv3s (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these makers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Subfolder Example

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
 
#SubDomain Example
 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
ReqriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
 
#END WordPress
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the "ea-php73" package as the default "PHP" programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Did you actually add the code for both the Subfolder and Subdomain to your htacess file, all at once? Try recreating your network following [this guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/) and be sure you use the [proper htacess code](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/).

Comment: Try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` at the top of the `.htaccess` file.